# Why does clearRect() method not clear an area on the canvas?

Tags: java, graphics, applet

I wrote a Java applet that prints a text on the canvas at the same position after getting updated in every iteration of a loop. The text value changes and the output is correct but the **clearRect()** method I call in the loop to clear the area of the text before printing out each time doesn't work and the text gets overwritten. I can see the output up to 2-3 iterations but then it's not readable. The applet actually performs a countdown and displays the time in **HH : MM : SS** format. Below is my code. Please predict the cause of this and/or correct it:

```
/* Only the section of the code I'm having problems in is included */

while (t>=0) {
    //int t stores total time in seconds
    int h=(t/3600);
    int m=((t%3600)/60);
    int s=((t%3600)%60);
    str=h+" : "+m+" : "+s;
    /* String str holds data to be displayed, i.e., time in HH : MM : SS format */
    g.clearRect(20,200,150,30);
    g.drawString(str,20,200);
    try{
        Thread.sleep(1000); //elapses 1 second
    }
    catch(Exception e) {}
    t=t-1;
}
```

Comment: If you read the Javadocs for clearRect it says: "Beginning with Java 1.1, the background color of offscreen images may be system dependent. Applications should use setColor followed by fillRect to ensure that an offscreen image is cleared to a specific color". You have seemingly failed to follow these instructions.

Comment: @ControlAltDel I haven't gone through the Javadocs and I really don't know about that instruction. I'm a newbie and haven't taken any professional courses; just bought a book and learned myself. I understood from your comment that the fillRect() method can be used but I still don't understand the use of clearRect(). Plus I also don't know about offscreen images. May I ask you to illustrate the syntax for correctly using clearRect()? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use drawRect with a color instead of clearRect. just like how @ControlAltDel explained it. I am not sure if that code above is located in your paint or run. I would still recommend to have runnable method instead of drawing it in a loop. Similar to [this link](http://johnbokma.com/java/applet-animation.html). Good luck

Comment: Alright. I'll first set the color to the default background color i.e., white and then use `g.fillRect(20,200,150,30)` to erase that area on the canvas. That's what I can do till I learn more about the runnable method and can do it the other way. Thanks @ZaidQureshi and @AltControlDel for helping me out.

Comment: also if you are trying to do a count down,  use (System.currentTimeMillis() + countDownTime) to store your end time then you can do `timer = EndTime - System.currentTimeMillis()` to show timer going down accurately

Comment: To be honest you dont need to know too much before using the Runnable, just know that paint will be called every time repaint() is called you can learn about the rest later. Use the same while loop in the run method. You can probably take the template from the link I provided